# Custom function to manipulate list not working in mutate when it does work in isolation

Tags: r, string, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame where one column is a list of keystrokes. I have then created a custom function to convert the list of keystrokes into the final word. As a concrete example, I start with this data:

```
dat <- data.frame(word=c(1,1,2,2,2,2),
                  key=c("a","b","a","b","Backspace","c"))
```

I then call the below to create a column with lists of keystrokes (the repeats are intentional, as I need to preserve every individual keystroke):

```
dat <- dat %>% 
  group_by(word) %>% 
  mutate(key_list = I(list(key))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This creates a data frame where the first 2 rows have key_list = `a,b` and the last 4 rows are `a,b,Backspace,c`. This is to be expected.

I then want to concatenate the key_list into a single string. However, I've created the custom function below because when iterating through the list, if I encounter "Backspace", I need to delete the last keystroke. Therefore, the function looks like:

```
library(tidyverse)

word_list_to_final_str <- function(word_list) {
  final_list = c()
  for (i in word_list) {
    if (tolower(i) %in% c(letters)) {
      final_list <- c(final_list, tolower(i))
    }
    else if (i == 'Backspace') {
      final_list <- head(final_list, -1)
    }
  }
  final_str <- str_c(final_list,collapse="")
  return(final_str)
}
```

When I run this function in isolation, it returns the correct result:

```
19:13:11> word_list_to_final_str(c("a","b","Backspace","c"))
[1] "ac"
```

However, when I run the function within `mutate()`, I get an additional column with all "abababbackspacecabbackspacecabbackspacecabbackspacec".

```
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(final_word = word_list_to_final_str(key_list))
```

Clearly somewhere the function is not clearing the list, but I cannot understand where. How can I change the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a list column, you need to map over that list. You can use `purrr` to make that pretty easy

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(word) %>% 
  mutate(key_list = I(list(key))) %>% 
  mutate(final_word = purrr:::map_chr(key_list, word_list_to_final_str))
```

An every more "tidy" way to do this would be to use `tidyr::nest` as well

```
dat %>% 
  tidyr::nest(key_list = c(key)) %>% 
  mutate(final_word = purrr::map_chr(key_list, ~word_list_to_final_str(.x$key)))
```

Comment: Very cool. Why does this mapping function work but the function call within mutate didn't work?

Comment: Mutate operates on all rows at the same time. So your function would need to accommodate a list of vectors rather than just a vector. Using `map` does the work of calling the function once for each row/vector in the list column.

Answer (score 1):

Without writing the function, you could do:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(word)%>%
  mutate(final_word = str_remove(str_c(key, collapse = ''), ".Backspace"))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   word [2]
   word key       final_word
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>     
1     1 a         ab        
2     1 b         ab        
3     2 a         ac        
4     2 b         ac        
5     2 Backspace ac        
6     2 c         ac
```

Comment: Could you explain how the combination of `str_remove` with `str_c` works to remove the Backspace and the last character? I'm having trouble understanding the structure of the nested functions.

Comment: @Adam_G str_remove deletes the word Backspace and also any character that comes before the word Backspace. Note that there is a `.` before Backspace. `.` is a regex metacharacter which represents anything. Check more on regular expressions